# Lua custom registry and LUA_REGISTRYINDEX

Tags: lua, registry

I need to mimic Lua's lua_ref registry, but not using the existing solution. Two questions related to it:

1. is the lua_ref/LUA_REGISTRYINDEX internally optimized in any way, or would the custom solution be equally fast?
2. LUA_REGISTRYINDEX is a pseudoindex - can we somehow define our own?
3. Is the answer for either question is different in different versions of Lua (including LuaJIT)?

Comment: Value of [`LUA_REGISTRYINDEX`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lua.h.html#LUA_REGISTRYINDEX) and that is not in the globals table. That is a special stack index.

Comment: Implementation of [`luaL_ref`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lauxlib.c.html#luaL_ref).

Comment: `luaL_ref` also works on whatever table you want, the registry is not a special table in any other way that I'm aware of, so just pass `luaL_ref` your own table.

Comment: Ah yeah, too long not working with Lua. So basically there's no way to mimic this functionality? I'm not interested in luaL_ref/luaL_unref, I'm interested in the stack index functionality for fast lookup.

Comment: No, you can't create your own pseudo-indices... at least not without compiling your own version of lua. See [`index2adr`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lapi.c.html#index2adr). But unless you've profiled extensively I wouldn't put money on this lookup being a bottleneck. Especially if you stick your table in the registry itself.

Comment: It's an extra integer lookup (twice in Lua 5.2). What I want is to get a custom table in a single integer rawgeti, as this operation will be done extensively. I considered using LUA_REGISTRYINDEX with negative numbers, but I don't know how it will affect other ops, and whether the indices will be stored in the array portion of the hybrid lua table...

Comment: I wouldn't stick anything unexpected in the registry, that sounds like a bad idea. Why can't you just use the registry normally for this? Is the concern that it will interact with other uses of the registry in some unpleasant way?

Comment: I need a compile-time index due to templating.

Comment: You could always write your own function like `index2adr` so that you can use a static index in that call and get a registry index back from it. Though that is extra overhead.

Comment: Well yes, but that still requires a global state, and introduces another level of indirection :/.

Comment: Unfortunate, but true. I don't know that you have any other choices though.

Comment: You can use upvalue to store your registry table. I use it in my modules (e.g. https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3/blob/master/src/lcmulti.c#L44)

Comment: @moteus - interesting - can you elaborate on that? Isn't the upvalue tied to a single function?

Comment: You can use same table as upvalue for several functions.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz It does not have to be a deep copy. You can store references to the same table everywhere, in an upvalue, as well as the global environment, or local variables.

Answer (score 1):

> is the lua_ref/LUA_REGISTRYINDEX internally optimized in any way, or would the custom solution be equally fast?

Outside of the fact that the registry is a special location accessible from any C function, there's nothing special about it. `luaL_ref` and its associates aren't special.

> LUA_REGISTRYINDEX is a pseudoindex - can we somehow define our own?

No. Well, not without modifying Lua itself.

You could in theory use upvalues, but every function you register has independent upvalues. Obviously they could all be referencing the *same* table. But the main thing is that this table wouldn't be visible outside of a function you have registered.

If that limitation is viable for you, then that should be good enough.